# React: what happens to life cycle methods when props object changes?

Tags: reactjs

I read this article: https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-react-lifecycle-methods-ddc79699b34e

and it says clearly: "If props or state of a component are changed for whatever reason, an update of the component is performed. However, this means that the component has to be re-rendered, which causes the following methods to be called:... shouldComponentUpdate()...."

Now, I wrote this component:

```
export default class MyComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    click() {
        this.props = {name: "John"};
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        console.log("change in props");
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1> {this.props.myText} </h1>
            <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}> click me </button>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

I expect that once I click the button, I'll get a message in console saying: "change in props".

But, it didn't happen. 
Do you know why?

Comment: Never assign directly to props. Props are always passed down from parent components / through component instantiation. that's like a method internally assigning its own arguments, it's not designed to work that way. a parent changing a child's props isn't assigning directly to `props = {}`

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate should return boolean value and change this.props = ... to this.setState({ name: 'John'} )    and in render use {this.state.name}. It will be state change. If you need props change, you must to change it in parent component (see answer below)

Comment: Those comments should be answers really.

Comment: @AndyRay, If so, what did the article that I attached mean by saying "If props ... of a component are changed"? How are they supposed to change?\

Answer (score 0):

After a small research, I found out that 'props' object is not supposed to be changed by the component itself. The only way to change it is by re-rendering the parent component that creates the child component that holds the props.

For example,

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: "Hiush!"
        };
    }

    click() {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {value: 'Biush!'}
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComp value={this.state.value}/>
                <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}> Click Me!! </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export class MyComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        console.log("change in props");
        return true;
    }
    render() {
        return <h1> {this.props.value} </h1>
    }
}
```

App is the parent component of MyComp. When click method in App is invoked, the state object of App is changed. Therefore, 'render' method in App is called, and MyComp is returned from 'render'. The content of 'this.state.value' is changed, and then the props object of MyComp is changed either.